# '.' is not recognized when attempting to run assembly code?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I made some code in assembly, and put the .asm file in the NASM folder

did the commands:
`nasm -f elf test.asm` and `ld test.o -o test` in the nasm console

but when I attempted to do ./test to run the code,
I got the error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

All the sites I visit to figure out how to run assembly code say I should just do ./thingy.asm but that clearly isn't working so I don't know what to do!

If it helps my OS is Windows 10, and my NASM version is 2.15.05

Comment: There is probably a really simple explanation to this but I am a little too stupid to find it myself /:

Comment: Windows programs have EXE extensions and you do not run them from the local directory by putting a `./`. `./` applies to Unix like system.

Comment: So then how do I run my program after its compiled?

Comment: assemble* not compile

Comment: Well you don't show the code to your program. I hope it uses the Windows calling convention. If it is a Windows program you would have to output a file called `test.exe` with the linker (ld) rather than a file called `test`. You would then run it by typing `test.exe` on the command line. If you showed your program I'd tell you if what you have would actually work. I am concerned about what kind of program you are creating since you are using `elf`

Comment: Well I was just told to use elf, but now that I just did nasm -h it says it is for unix, I am on windows, so I don't think that elf will even work, I am assuming I just just do bin or win
ps. oops im commenting on my alt again

Comment: ELF is okay if you linker can still output a windows EXE. What does the command `ld -mnone` give as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
> ```

**Background information**

The reason is that Windows works differently from Linux or Unix (and obvously your tutorials describe how to work with Linux):

If a file name ends with `.exe`, Windows recognizes the file as application program. If a file name ends with `.bat`, Windows recognizes the file as "batch" file.

Under Linux or Unix this is completely different: An application or "batch" (*) file can have any file name; a file is "marked" with a special flag telling the operating system that the file can be executed. If this flag is set, the operating system uses the file content (not the suffix of the file name) to distinguish the type of executable file (e.g. application, "batch" file, Python program ...).

The command line `ld test.o -o test` will generate a file that is named `test`, not `test.exe`. Under Linux this would be a valid file name for an application, under Windows the file name must end with `.exe`, so this is not a valid file name.

You are free to name a "batch" file `test.exe` and an application `test.bat` under Linux if you like to do so.

Under Linux the command `./test` would start an application named `test` in the current directory; `./test.exe` would start an application or "batch" file named `test.exe`.

Under Windows, the command for executing the file named `test.exe` would simply be `test`, not `./test.exe`.

**About your problem**

First of all, you'll have to rename your output file: `ld test.o -o test.exe`

The next problem is that your program will definitely not work on Windows:

At least Windows 7 (I'm not sure about Windows 10) will refuse starting an application not using any DLL files; and the command line `ld test.o -o test.exe` generates an application that does not use any DLL files.

I'm quite sure your assembly program contains the `int` instruction or the `syscall` instruction.

Directly calling these instructions is operating system specific:

A program that calls `int 0x80` (or `int 80h` or `int $0x80` depending on the assembler used) will run on Linux only!

---

(*) This file type is named "shell script", not "batch file" in Linux; however, this is mainly a difference in terminology.